# How can I make Content centered- in bootstrap card?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to center content in this card

```
<!-- Card -->
<div class="card card-image h-80" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4 justify-content">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i> Your Holdings</h5>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong id="snet-holding">0 </strong> SNET</h3>
      <h4 class="card-title pt-2"><strong id="usd-value">0 </strong> USD</h4>

      <br>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->

    </div>
```

but for some reason the contenet inside the card only centers when there is a value inside it. But i need to have it centered also if there is no content inside it. 
I need to have content centered when in this state of the image

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but to tidy your code up you should remove those <br> tags and use a margin-bottom class H5 e.g. mb-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be `justify-content-center` class instead of `justify-content`. **The new code is**

```
<div class="card card-image h-80" style="background-color:grey;">

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="text-white text-center d-flex align-items-center rgba-black-strong py-5 px-4 justify-content-center">
    <div>
      <h5 class="pink-text"><i class="fas fa-chart-pie" aria-hidden="true"></i> Your Holdings</h5>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3 class="card-title pt-2"><strong id="snet-holding">0 </strong> SNET</h3>
      <h4 class="card-title pt-2"><strong id="usd-value">0 </strong> USD</h4>

      <br>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```